# tIECategory table existed, but keep falling into "else" section... any of code wrong or something else?

Tags: java, sql

```
DatabaseMetaData md = conn.getMetaData();

//int numberOfColumns = metaData.getColumnCount();

ResultSet rm = md.getTables(null, null, "tIECategory", null);

if (rm.next()) {                       
    System.out.println("Table exists");
} else {
    //createTable(tables[i]);
    System.out.println("No such table-IEReport Class");
}
```

Comment: 1. Check if you are connecting to correct database 
2. Check the Connection user's priviledege to access that table
3. Verify the table name, It can be a case sensitive issue

Comment: Thanks for the comment
But capitalized table name solved problem
Any idea why?

Comment: @Hana: because the SQL standard requires that unquoted identifiers are stored in upper case (although not all DBMS products do it that way)